# Connecting with invoke-sqlcmd works but msoldedbsql gives "prelogin failure"

Tags: sql-server, azure

This is an Azure networking issue but a weird one.
I am trying to connect from an Azure VM to an on-prem sql server (SQL Server 2012 SP4; yes, old and we're trying to move off of it, but we see the problem on newer versions as well). Port 1433 is opened, and I can connect using invoke-sqlcmd successfully, but not from MSOLEDBSQL

```
$ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Database=master;User Id=$user;Password=$password;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $ConnectionString -Query "select @@servername"
```

However, if I use the MSOLEDBSQL driver, I get "client unable to establish connection due to prelogin failure". And if I look in system_health, I see my old nemesis 17830,

```
SniProvider OSError SniConsumerError    State
7           NULL    17830               105
```

Here's the query for msoledbsql:

```
$Client_type='MSOLEDBSQL'
$ConnectionString = "Provider=$Client_type;Server=$server;Database=master;UID=$user;PWD=$password;Encrypt=yes;Trust Server Certificate=true;"
$SQLquery = "select @@servername as servername"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$comm = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($SQLquery,$conn)
$conn.Open()
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $comm
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet)
$conn.Close()
$table = $dataset.Tables[0]
$table
```

Comment: Why not use `System.Data.SqlClient` instead of `System.Data.OleDb`?

Comment: Given Microsoft's propensity for deprecating and un-deprecating `SQLOLEDB` on a whim I'd avoid using it in any development. If you have .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later available on the target system(s) you'd be much better served using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, which is actively developed and receives feature updates for modern versions of Azure and on-prem SQL Server versions, with the latest version of `System.Data.SqlClient` you can lay your hands on as a fallback (it's not that actively developed any more, either).

Comment: Does `test-netconnection $server -port 1433` succeed?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yeah, the code we have is older SSIS code, and the string is from the first time before it got deprecated.

Comment: @DanGuzman I was trying to mirror what was in the SSIS package, which had that driver. We moved it to SQLNCLI11.1 (which, yes, is old and now unmaintained) and it works. Can't explain it, but I'll take the win.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes, it succeeded. And the fix we're rolling with for now is to move to SQLNCLI11.1, as that doesn't throw the error and is supported in the SSIS package that's the source of the trouble. (I used powershell code here since it's easier to use for a repro)

Comment: @mbourgon, I recommend you give `System.Data.SqlClient` a try.